# Horizontal Scroll not working perfectly in react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am making a blog website and want the filter section to scroll horizontally to accommodate all of the filters from the list.
Using tailwindCSS so I added `overflow-x-auto` but it doesn't go all the way through from start to end, instead it starts from somewhere in the middle.

```
const list = [
  "all",
  "tech",
  "design",
  "sports",
  "politics",
  "entertainment",
  "study",
]

export const Filters = () => {
  return (
    <div className="max-w-screen flex justify-evenly p-4 gap-4 overflow-x-auto">
      {list.map((item, idx) => {
        return (
          <button className="capitalize" key={idx}>
            {item}
          </button>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

It should start from start and go all the way to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing the `justify-evenly` class. This would apply `justify-content: space-evenly`. This would mean that the browser aligns the content *before* the scrollable length is calculated.

```js
const list = [
  "all",
  "tech",
  "design",
  "sports",
  "politics",
  "entertainment",
  "study",
]

const Filters = () => {
  return (
    <div className="max-w-screen flex p-4 gap-4 overflow-x-auto">
      {list.map((item, idx) => {
        return (
          <button className="capitalize" key={idx}>
            {item}
          </button>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<Filters/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```